# How to get the last item added to firebase cloud functions realtime database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have a simple realtime firebase db with the following structure

notification:

- 100000

  - info: "this is my info0"
- 100001

  - info: "this is my info1"
- 100002

  - info: "this is my info2"

I need to read the info in the last child and have this function in index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.helloWorld = 
functions.database.ref('/notification').onWrite((snapshot, context) => {
   const myData = context.info;
  console.log('data: '+myData);
});
```

but the console log give me an error:

helloWorld
**Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value**

and I hope to get in the console: **data: this is my info2**

what is wrong in my code?

thanks!

**UPDATE:**

to read the last value i need to change

const myData = context.info;

to:

const myData = snapshot.after.val();

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something in the trigger function. `null` are acceptable. If you want to get the last child everywhen you create, use `onCreate` instead of `onWrite`. The doc said:

> onCreate(), which triggers when new data is created in the Realtime Database.

You maybe want to check this example: [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data)

Comment: i still get the same error.(i'm triggering the function writing new data in the db, is not null)

11:05:47.409 p.m. helloWorld  **data undefined**
11:05:47.413 p.m. helloWorld  **Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value**
11:05:47.601 p.m. helloWorld  Function execution took 293 ms, finished with status: 'ok'

Comment: @ALEXANDERLOZANO What exact change you did to the Cloud Function code? Can you update your question with the new code please?

Answer (score 0):

i need to change from:

const myData = context.info;

to:

const myData = snapshot.after.val();

then i get the last item value.

Comment: be careful with `onWrite`.